# How to compile and output code on the Command line? Mac os Xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I recently switched from windows to mac os and started using xcode as a c++ development environment, I'm still learning, so I don't know how to compile and output the results of the written code to the command line/terminal

все перегулял ничо не нашел

Comment: Why would you use Xcode as "development environment" and at the same want to "compile and output the results on command line"? Xcode has a shiny "run" button you can push.

Comment: I wrote a simple toy that works on the command line, I tried to compile it and run it already on Mac os via Xcode, but here it turned out to be much more difficult to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile code in the terminal just use `ls` and `cd` to go to your source dir and use the command

```
clang++ source.c -o output
```

and to run it use:

```
./output
```

I suppose you got xcode command line tools installed, if not, use the command `xcode-select --install`. Also on macos there isn't gcc in xcode (the command `gcc` is a alias to clang), to get gcc, get [brew](https://brew.sh/) and install gcc with `brew install gcc` and use it as `gcc-12`

Comment: Of course, it's not as convenient as on windows, everything works there in Visual Studio through the Run button, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Woah you mean windows is more convenient :O Unix stuff is certainly better when you get stuff right (like using `oh my zsh` for autocomplete, use `iTerm`...)

Comment: If you want a auto build button you can try out `CLion`, 'Sublime text` or `Vscode` (I don't really like vscode :P) I don't really like XCode since it's too heavy, it is mainly only used for developing ios and (some) macos applications

Comment: Yes, I wasn't going to seriously use Xcode to program in c++, I just wanted to run my first program on Mac os, just to remember it. Now I'm trying to deal with Mac os analogues of getch() and system("cls"), which I used in Windows.

Comment: For the `system("cls")`, just use `system("clear")`. and for `getch`, there isn't a function for macos, maby try using ncurses for you program :)

Comment: Getch I need it for an interactive menu that can be controlled by arrows, that is, I used it to read the code of a character like this
 (
 switch (getchar()) {
           case 13:
               return checker;
               break;
)

Comment: XCode has a built-in console (it's at the bottom of the window). You can edit the Scheme to use Terminal instead of the XCode console.

Comment: It would be great to know how to do that.

Comment: So, I figured it out and changed the scheme, thank you very much